# Ошибка при вызове программы на Python через cmd

Tags: python, cmd, машинное-обучение

В Python был написан скрипт, подтягивающий объект pickle модели машинного обучения. При вводе в скрипт аргументов он должен пропускать их через модель и выводить на печать  результаты ее расчетов. 
Листинг скрипта:

```
import sys
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import pickle
import re
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

def createParser ():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument ('name',  nargs='+')
    return parser


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = createParser()
    namespace = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    # Список аргументов на вход
    columnsList = ['data.info.blockOgrn.text',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.0.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.1.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks_0.cases.2.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.3.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.4.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.5.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.6.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.7.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.8.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.9.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.count'
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.sum',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12004]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12303]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12304]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[13103]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[14003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[15003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[15203]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.class',
                   'data.executions.blocks.0.sum',
                   'data.executions.blocks.1.sum']
    df_in = pd.DataFrame(namespace.name, index=columnsList).T

    for n in df_in.columns:
        if n not in ['data.executions.blocks.0.sum','data.executions.blocks.1.sum']:
            df_in[n]=df_in[n].astype('float')               

    # Разбиение столбцов типа "Х на сумму У" на пары столбцов типа Х и У.                
    df_in[['num_successful_executions','num_successful_executions_sum']] = df_in['data.executions.blocks.0.sum'].str.split('\s*на сумму\s*', expand=True)
    df_in.drop(columns='data.executions.blocks.0.sum', inplace=True)


    df_in[['num_continuing_executions','num_continuing_executions_sum']] = df_in['data.executions.blocks.1.sum'].str.split('\s*на сумму\s*', expand=True)
    df_in.drop(columns='data.executions.blocks.1.sum', inplace=True)

   # приведение столбцов Х и Y к количественному типу
    df_in['num_continuing_executions']=pd.to_numeric(df_in['num_continuing_executions'],errors='coerce')
    df_in['num_successful_executions']=pd.to_numeric(df_in['num_successful_executions'],errors='coerce')

    df_in['num_continuing_executions'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df_in['num_successful_executions'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

    for n in ['num_continuing_executions_sum','num_successful_executions_sum']:
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('руб', '')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('млн', '00000')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('млрд', '00000000')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('Нет', '0')
        df_in[n].fillna('0', inplace=True)
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('.', '')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace(',', '')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace(' ', '')
        df_in[n]=pd.to_numeric(df_in[n], errors='coerce')

    # Вычленение из столбца типа xxYYzzMM информации типа YY

    df_in['data.info.blockOgrn.text'] = df_in['data.info.blockOgrn.text'].map(lambda x: str(x)[3:5])
    df_in['data.info.blockOgrn.text']=pd.to_numeric(df_in['data.info.blockOgrn.text'])

    # Создание флаговых столбцов, маркирующих отсутствующие значения столбцов ниже

    for n in ['data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12004]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12303]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12304]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[13103]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[14003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[15003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[15203]']:
        df_in[n+'_no_data_flag']=np.where(df_in[n]==np.nan,1,0)



    # load the model from disk
    filename1 = 'D:\knn_model.pickle'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename1, 'rb'))
    y2_pred = loaded_model.predict(df_in)

    # Вывод
    wished_sum =float(input())
    prob = 95*float(y2_pred)/float(wished_sum)
    if prob>=95:
        prob = 95
    print("{:.1f} ".format(y2_pred),'\n',wished_sum, '{:.1f} %'.format(prob))
```

Аргументов 23, и они в командную строку подаются в такой последовательности и формате:

> 1027700092661 15000 23000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 38000 23000 34000 15000
>   17000 10000 80000 72000 1 "2 на сумму 3000" "3  на сумму 34500"

Выплывает ошибка в командной строке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 350, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "sklearn\neighbors\binary_tree.pxi", line 1294, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query
ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 699, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 359, in __call__
    raise TransportableException(text, e_type)
sklearn.externals.joblib.my_exceptions.TransportableException: TransportableException
___________________________________________________________________________
ValueError                                         Wed Dec 12 14:05:28 2018
PID: 13792                             Python 3.6.5: C:\anaconda\python.exe
...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=<sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchedCalls object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        self.items = [(<built-in method query of sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree object>, (array([[7.70e+01, 1.50e+04, 2.30e+04, 0.00e+00, ...0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00]]), 4, True), {})]
    132
    133     def __len__(self):
    134         return self._size
    135

...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0=<list_iterator object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        func = <built-in method query of sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree object>
        args = (array([[7.70e+01, 1.50e+04, 2.30e+04, 0.00e+00, ...0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00]]), 4, True)
        kwargs = {}
    132
    133     def __len__(self):
    134         return self._size
    135

...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\kd_tree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query()

ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension
___________________________________________________________________________

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Execution_prediction.py", line 101, in <module>
    y2_pred = loaded_model.predict(df_in)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\regression.py", line 144, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 385, in kneighbors
    for s in gen_even_slices(X.shape[0], n_jobs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 789, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 740, in retrieve
    raise exception
sklearn.externals.joblib.my_exceptions.JoblibValueError: JoblibValueError
___________________________________________________________________________
Multiprocessing exception:
...........................................................................
D:\Execution_prediction.py in <module>()
     96
     97
     98     # load the model from disk
     99     filename1 = 'D:\knn_model.pickle'
    100     loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename1, 'rb'))
--> 101     y2_pred = loaded_model.predict(df_in)
    102
    103
    104     wished_sum =float(input())
    105     prob = 95*float(y2_pred)/float(wished_sum)

...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\regression.py in predict(self=KNeighborsRegressor(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=... n_neighbors=4, p=1,
          weights='uniform'), X=array([[7.70e+01, 1.50e+04, 2.30e+04, 0.00e+00, ...0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00]]))
    139         y : array of int, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]
    140             Target values
    141         """
    142         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    143
--> 144         neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
        neigh_dist = undefined
        neigh_ind = undefined
        self.kneighbors = <bound method KNeighborsMixin.kneighbors of KNei...n_neighbors=4, p=1,
          weights='uniform')>
        X = array([[7.70e+01, 1.50e+04, 2.30e+04, 0.00e+00, ...0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00]])
    145
    146         weights = _get_weights(neigh_dist, self.weights)
    147
    148         _y = self._y

...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in kneighbors(self=KNeighborsRegressor(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=... n_neighbors=4, p=1,
          weights='uniform'), X=array([[7.70e+01, 1.50e+04, 2.30e+04, 0.00e+00, ...0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00]]), n_neighbors=4, return_distance=True)
    380                     "%s does not work with sparse matrices. Densify the data, "
    381                     "or set algorithm='brute'" % self._fit_method)
    382             result = Parallel(n_jobs, backend='threading')(
    383                 delayed(self._tree.query, check_pickle=False)(
    384                     X[s], n_neighbors, return_distance)
--> 385                 for s in gen_even_slices(X.shape[0], n_jobs)
        X.shape = (1, 33)
        n_jobs = 8
    386             )
    387             if return_distance:
    388                 dist, neigh_ind = tuple(zip(*result))
    389                 result = np.vstack(dist), np.vstack(neigh_ind)

...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=Parallel(n_jobs=8), iterable=<generator object KNeighborsMixin.kneighbors.<locals>.<genexpr>>)
    784             if pre_dispatch == "all" or n_jobs == 1:
    785                 # The iterable was consumed all at once by the above for loop.
    786                 # No need to wait for async callbacks to trigger to
    787                 # consumption.
    788                 self._iterating = False
--> 789             self.retrieve()
        self.retrieve = <bound method Parallel.retrieve of Parallel(n_jobs=8)>
    790             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    791             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
    792             self._print('Done %3i out of %3i | elapsed: %s finished',
    793                         (len(self._output), len(self._output),

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub-process traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                         Wed Dec 12 14:05:28 2018
PID: 13792                             Python 3.6.5: C:\anaconda\python.exe
...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=<sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchedCalls object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        self.items = [(<built-in method query of sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree object>, (array([[7.70e+01, 1.50e+04, 2.30e+04, 0.00e+00, ...0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00]]), 4, True), {})]
    132
    133     def __len__(self):
    134         return self._size
    135

...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0=<list_iterator object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        func = <built-in method query of sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree object>
        args = (array([[7.70e+01, 1.50e+04, 2.30e+04, 0.00e+00, ...0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00]]), 4, True)
        kwargs = {}
    132
    133     def __len__(self):
    134         return self._size
    135

...........................................................................
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\kd_tree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query()

ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension
___________________________________________________________________________
```

Подскажите, как исправить, спасибо.

З.Ы. Возможно ошибка в аргументах в листе:

```
def createParser ():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument ('name',  nargs='+')
    return parser


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = createParser()
    namespace = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    # Список аргументов на вход
    columnsList = ['data.info.blockOgrn.text',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.0.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.1.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks_0.cases.2.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.3.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.4.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.5.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.6.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.7.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.8.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.cases.9.sum',
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.count'
                   'data.courtPractice.dashboard.blocks.0.sum',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12004]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12303]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[12304]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[13103]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[14003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[15003]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.lastYearBalance.values.[15203]',
                   'data.balanceCollection.profit.class',
                   'data.executions.blocks.0.sum',
                   'data.executions.blocks.1.sum']
    df_in = pd.DataFrame(namespace.name, index=columnsList).T
```

имеется ровно 24 столбца, но программа запрашивает почему то 23:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\1\Execution_prediction.py", line 52, in <module>
    df_in = pd.DataFrame(namespace.name, index=columnsList).T   File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 403, in
__init__
    copy=copy)   File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 536, in
_init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks([values], [columns, index])   File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4866, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)   File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4843, in construction_error
    passed, implied)) ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 24), indices imply (1, 23)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размерность (в данном случае число столбцов) DataFrame `df_in` не совпадает с размерностью набора данных, на котором обучали модель. Число и типы столбцов данных, подаваемых на вход модели должны совпадать с обучающей выборкой.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос описанием проблемы, если вводить в скрипт столько же аргументов сколько принимала модель

Comment: @StepanSokol, можете привести что представляет из себя `namespace.name`?

Comment: наверное нет, разве что из текста программы... Это перепиленный скрипт от программиста, который ушел. На его модели с его набором аргументов это работает. Если это может помочь могу выложить скрипт-исходник

Comment: Или по другому - что иначе можно подать на вход в pd.DataFrame, чтобы он подцепил ввод аргументов из cmd?

Comment: чтобы ответить надо иметь данные, поэтому я и спросил про `namespace.name`

Comment: Да, проблема именно в нем. Мораль - никогда не пользоваться чужим кодом, если непонятно как он работает. Я просто заменил этот 'namespace.name' на sys.argv[1:] и все заработало. Дальше осталось победить свои собственные баги